# How to switch user in single line using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to switch user with a single command.

I tried some commands but I failed:

```
su - jboss -p jboss@123
```

```
su - jboss / jboss@123
```

Here `jboss` is the username and `jboss@123` is the password.

Comment: Have you read the `su` man page? There is no option to provide a password. You could add a sudoers entry for this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

`su` does not take passwords as parameters.

What you could do is use `sudo` instead. `sudo` can be configured to work for specific command and users and can be configured not to use passwords at all.

Apart from that: Never put passwords into command lines or as parameters, because other users could see then using `ps`, `top`, `htop` or similar